# Cakephp 3 model find fails with contain anonymous function

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0

I get "An Internal Server Error Occurred" on this simple query:

```
$query = $this->find()
    ->contain(['CatLang' => function(Query $q) use($i18n){
      return $q->where(['CatLang.i18n' => $i18n]);
    }])
    ->where(['Categories.id' => $categoryId]);

$category = $query->first();
```

The tables look like this, simplified:

```
  categories
    id

  cat_lang
    category_id
    i18n
```

The models are named CategoriesTable and CatLangTable, both extending Table.

CatLangTable belongsTo Categories:

```
$this->belongsTo('Categories');
```

..and Categories hasMany CatLangs:

```
$this->hasMany('CatLang');
```

The query is run from a function in CategoriesTable. A working query in mysql would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM categories AS c 
INNER JOIN cat_lang as cl ON cl.category_id=c.id
WHERE c.id=13
AND cl.i18n='sv'
```

This query would return the result set from one row in categories with id 13, joined with one row from cat_lang where i18n equals 'sv'. (category_id and i18n have a unique index.)

Can anyone please advice me, what am I doing wrong?

Using cakephp 3.5.17, php 7, and mysql 5.7.

Comment: To get more details on the error, [**enable debug mode**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#general-configuration), and check your error logs.

Comment: I have it on and I get this: Error: [TypeError] Argument 1 passed to App\Model\Table\CategoriesTable::App\Model\Table\{closure}() must be an instance of App\Model\Table\Query, instance of Cake\ORM\Query given, calle in vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\ORM\Association\Loader\SelectLoader.php on line 195.

Comment: That means that you haven't [**imported**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) the name (properly) that you are using in the closures typehint for the `$q` argument. Either use the fully qualified name in the typehint, ie `\Cake\ORM\Query $q`, or add it to your imports, ie `use Cake\ORM\Query`.

Comment: Thank's ndm, I had forgotten this. I just tried it, but to my disappointment there is no change. I added "use Cake\ORM\Query;" and "use Cake\ORM\Table;" at the top of the file, to no avail.
Btw. I am actually copying the code from the docs:
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#passing-conditions-to-contain

Comment: ndm! It did work. I had added some debugs which ruined the code. Can you post your answer so I can mark it as the correct answer? Thank's a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. I'd probably rather vote to close the question, as it's merely more than a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bad. As ndm noted in the comments, I completely missed out to import the Query namespace.

```
use Cake\ORM\Query;
```

The error message was clear enough if I would have cared about reading it: :-)

```
App\Model\Table\CategoriesTable::App\Model\Table\{closure}() 
must be an instance of App\Model\Table\Query, 
instance of Cake\ORM\Query given
```

Hope it helps someone.